# List of iOS fonts grouped by supported script (ISO 15924)

Tags: ios, fonts, internationalization

So, obviously there's iosfonts.com which has been incredibly helpful, but how can I determine that, for example, HiraKakuProN-W3 contains the code points for Japanese, (Jpan, 413 in ISO 15924)

Furthermore, I'd like to know more specific information. I imagine that, continuing the example, HiraKakuProN contains the characters for Hiragana and Katakana, but does it also contain all the CJK unified ideographs, just the ones needed for Japanese, or none of them?

Where can I find exhaustive tables of unicode characters per *language* (IETF language tag)? It's easy to find a listing of all Hani characters, but Unicode (and the Hani code point table) doesn't make a distinction between Hans, Hant, Jpan, etc. I ask this because, if there is no readily available info on which iOS font is for which language, I will programmatically determine this myself, but will need to know what characters to look for.

Thanks for any leads.

Answer (score 0):

The list of supported ScriptCodes for Arial Unicode ( The most polyvalent font as far as I know) is there :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS

From this site, you can find a link to fonts supporting a given ScriptCode.
But it may need some font installations.
I hope it helps… This is a complex domain ;)

http://scriptsource.org/cms/scripts/page.php